# How to install ruby locally via rbenv/ruby-build?

Tags: ruby, rbenv, offline-mode

I require installing ruby **without internet access**. As `ruby-build` docs suggest I can change the mirror URL via specifying the environment variable `RUBY_BUILD_MIRROR_URL`. I did this and although it looks at my local repo for ruby it still attempts to connect to online repo to install `yaml`.

```
env RUBY_BUILD_MIRROR_URL=http://10.10.161.39/platforms/common/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz#3e71042872c77726409460e8647a2f304083a15ae0defe90d8000a69917e20d3 /opt/rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> http://10.152.161.39/platforms/proteus/common/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz#3e71042872c77726409460e8647a2f304083a15ae0defe90d8000a69917e20d3/7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749
-> http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz
error: failed to download yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz

BUILD FAILED (RedHatEnterpriseServer 5.10 using ruby-build 20150928)
```

I tried placing the `yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz` file in my local repo however that makes no difference besides it will fail since the `sha2` checksum provided in the URL is for `ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz` file.

How can install ruby offline with `rbenv`?

**Update 1**

I discovered that you can modify the lookup config file to point to a local mirror instead. i.e: `/opt/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/share/ruby-build/2.0.0-p247`

```
install_package "yaml-0.1.6" "http://10.10.161.39/platforms/common/yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz#7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749"  --if needs_yaml
install_package "openssl-1.0.1p" "ttp://10.10.161.39/platforms/common/openssl-1.0.1p.tar.gz#bd5ee6803165c0fb60bbecbacacf244f1f90d2aa0d71353af610c29121e9b2f1" mac_openssl --if has_broken_mac_openssl
install_package "ruby-2.0.0-p247"  "http://10.10.161.39/platforms/common/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz#3e71042872c77726409460e8647a2f304083a15ae0defe90d8000a69917e20d3"
```

Is there a better way or is this is the best way forward?

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?
I'm trying now and after moving ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2 to the machine I'm kinda stuck

Comment: Yes, it did work. I'll add some of the steps as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So here's how I got it to work:**

Update the contents of the download file in `/opt/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/share/ruby-build/<ruby-version>` to point to your local repo.

You will also notice how each file has a long hash valued after the '#' symbol in the URL. For Example:

`install_package "yaml-0.1.6" "http://10.10.161.39/platforms/common/yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz#7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749"  --if needs_yaml`

This hash value is the `sha256sum` the file which `rbenv` will use to validate if it is the expected file.

So you will need to generate the value by running `sha256sum <filename>` and appending to each file in the URL path.

**Complete example below:**

```
install_package "yaml-0.1.6" "http://10.10.161.39/platforms/common/yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz#7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749"  --if needs_yaml
install_package "openssl-1.0.1p" "ttp://10.10.161.39/platforms/common/openssl-1.0.1p.tar.gz#bd5ee6803165c0fb60bbecbacacf244f1f90d2aa0d71353af610c29121e9b2f1" mac_openssl --if has_broken_mac_openssl
install_package "ruby-2.0.0-p247"  "http://10.10.161.39/platforms/common/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz#3e71042872c77726409460e8647a2f304083a15ae0defe90d8000a69917e20d3"
```

In the example above we have a dedicated repository server at `http://10.10.161.39/platforms/common`. If your packages are locally available, you will need to point to the local path and verify if it works.